# Attempting to Redirect to User Profile

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, buddypress

Using BuddyPress, I am attempting to redirect all registered users to their user profile; however when redirecting the resulting URL is not including the user_login... as a result every user is redirecting to "domain/members/".

How can I get the username to show up in the URL to then redirect to the following: "domain/members/username/"?

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
add_filter('login_redirect', function ($redirect_to, $request, $user){
    if (user_can($user, 'registered')){
      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      return '/members/' . $current_user->user_login . '/';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the WordPress Codex: "The $current_user global may not be available at the time this filter is run. So you should use the $user global or the $user parameter passed to this filter."

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

```
add_filter('login_redirect', function ($redirect_to, $request, $user){
    if (user_can($user, 'registered')){
        return bp_core_get_user_domain( $user->ID );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    function redirect_to($new_location) {
      header("Location: " . $new_location);
      exit;
    }
```

redirect function call this function as redirect_to("redirect_page");

Comment: Using WordPress, not pure PHP.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach that doesn't rely on a hard-coded slug:

```
return bp_core_get_user_domain( $user->ID );
```

Comment: Thank you for the core function.